# Smooth Hilbert curves

Tags: math, graphics, curve-fitting, bezier

I'm trying to smooth out the path taken by a [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#History). I can define the points and connect them by straight lines, but I want a path that doesn't take the edges so sharply. I attempted to connect the curve using Bezier curves of higher and higher orders but this doesn't work, there are always 'kinks' in the path as I try to reconnect them:

[image]

I feel like this a solved problem, but I'm not searching for the right terms.

Comment: How would you define which points to include in the curve and which ones to discard? A smooth curve connecting all points will likely self-intersect.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog good question, but I don't need it to hit all the points, but rather come close to them, and be smooth.

Comment: You are not using one Bezier curve here. Instead, you have multiple Bezier curves (each with four control points) patched together. What you want is a spline (probably a [B-spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline)).

Comment: You have just wrongly connected your curves higher degree curves will not help instead it would create self-intersection problems. For this purpose stick with 4 point cubics and do this in piecewise manner... See my answer (especially the part where `p0,p1,p2,p3` points are computed)  and the links in there

Comment: @Hooked I tried to implement 3D look here [Mapping Hilbert values to 3D points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50488348/2521214) is the result (got rid of the turtle gfx for 2D too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using piecewise cubics for this... Does not really matter if **BEZIER SPLINE** or whatever. You just need to connect the patches with proper point call sequence which you clearly did not do. Here is my example using [my Interpolation cubics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20517874/2521214) with proper call sequence:

[image: smooth hilbert]

Gray is the turtle graphics original Hilbert curve and Aqua is the interpolated cubic curve for the same points ...

Was curious so I wanted to implement this but Took me a while to figure out and implement **2D** Hilbert curves (I used turtle graphics) as I never used them before. Here **OpenGL VCL C++** source code for this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double ha=0.0; AnsiString hs="";    // turtle graphics
List<double> pnt;                   // 2D point list
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void turtle_mirror(AnsiString &s)   // swap l,r
    {
    int i,l; char c;
    for (l=s.Length(),i=1;i<=l;i++)
        {
        c=s[i];
        if (c=='l') s[i]='r';
        if (c=='r') s[i]='l';
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void turtle_hilbert(AnsiString &s,double &a,int n)  // compute hilbert curve turtle string s , line segment size a for n iterations
    {
    int i,l; char c;
    AnsiString s0;
    if (s=="") { l=1; s="frfrf"; }  // init hilbert curve assuming starting bottom left turned up
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        s0=s;                   // generator
        if (int(i&1)==0)        // even pass
            {
            turtle_mirror(s0); s ="r"+s0+"rf";
            turtle_mirror(s0); s+=s0+"lfl"+s0;
            turtle_mirror(s0); s+="fr"+s0;
            }
        else{                   // odd pass
            turtle_mirror(s0); s ="r"+s0+"f";
            turtle_mirror(s0); s+=s0+"fl"+s0;
            turtle_mirror(s0); s+="rfr"+s0;
            }
        l=l+l+1;                // adjust scale
        }
    a=1.0/double(l);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void turtle_draw(double x,double y,double dx,double dy,const AnsiString &s)
    {
    int i,l; char c;
    double q;
    l=s.Length();
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    glVertex2d(x,y);
    for (i=1;i<=l;i++)
        {
        c=s[i];
        if (c=='f') { x+=dx; y+=dy; glVertex2d(x,y); }
        if (c=='l') { q=dx; dx=-dy; dy= q; }
        if (c=='r') { q=dx; dx= dy; dy=-q; }
        }
    glEnd();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void turtle_compute(List<double> &xy,double x,double y,double dx,double dy,const AnsiString &s)
    {
    int i,l; char c;
    double q;
    l=s.Length();
    xy.num=0;   // clear list
    xy.add(x);  // add point
    xy.add(y);
    for (i=1;i<=l;i++)
        {
        c=s[i];
        if (c=='f') { x+=dx; y+=dy; xy.add(x); xy.add(y); }
        if (c=='l') { q=dx; dx=-dy; dy= q; }
        if (c=='r') { q=dx; dx= dy; dy=-q; }
        }
    glEnd();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    //_redraw=false;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLint id;
    glUseProgram(prog_id);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // hilber curve covering <-1,+1> range
    if (hs=="")
        {
        turtle_hilbert(hs,ha,3);                        // init turtle string
        turtle_compute(pnt,-0.9,-0.9,0.0,1.8*ha,hs);    // init point list for curve fit
        }
    // render hs,ha as turtle graphics
    glColor3f(0.4,0.4,0.4);
    turtle_draw(-0.9,-0.9,0.0,1.8*ha,hs);
    // render pnt[] as interpolation cubics
    int i,j;
    double  d1,d2,t,tt,ttt,*p0,*p1,*p2,*p3,a0[2],a1[2],a2[2],a3[2],p[2];
    glColor3f(0.2,0.7,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (i=-2;i<pnt.num;i+=2) // process whole curve
        { // here create the call sequence (select control points)
        j=i-2; if (j<0) j=0; if (j>=pnt.num) j=pnt.num-2; p0=pnt.dat+j;
        j=i  ; if (j<0) j=0; if (j>=pnt.num) j=pnt.num-2; p1=pnt.dat+j;
        j=i+2; if (j<0) j=0; if (j>=pnt.num) j=pnt.num-2; p2=pnt.dat+j;
        j=i+4; if (j<0) j=0; if (j>=pnt.num) j=pnt.num-2; p3=pnt.dat+j;
        for (j=0;j<2;j++) // compute curve parameters
            {
            d1=0.5*(p2[j]-p0[j]);
            d2=0.5*(p3[j]-p1[j]);
            a0[j]=p1[j];
            a1[j]=d1;
            a2[j]=(3.0*(p2[j]-p1[j]))-(2.0*d1)-d2;
            a3[j]=d1+d2+(2.0*(-p2[j]+p1[j]));
            }
        for (t=0.0;t<=1.0;t+=0.05)  // single curve patch/segment
            {
            tt=t*t;
            ttt=tt*t;
            for (j=0;j<2;j++) p[j]=a0[j]+(a1[j]*t)+(a2[j]*tt)+(a3[j]*ttt);
            glVertex2dv(p);
            }
        }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I do not think the curves would self-intersect and for all the `n` I tried they did not because the rounding is confined very near to the edges and increasing recursion will scale it too so the gap remains.

I used `AnsiString` type from **VCL** which is string (accessed from index `1` !) capable of string arithmetics like adding string etc ...

I also use mine dynamic list template so:

`List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`

`xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list

`xxx[7]` access array element (safe)

`xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)

`xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array

`xxx.reset()` clears the array and set `xxx.num=0`

`xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

for the curve points you can use any dynamic list structure you got at your disposal instead.

The rendering is done by **OpenGL 1.0** (old style api) so porting that should be easy ...

Function:

```
void turtle_hilbert(AnsiString &s,double &a,int n);
```

will generate turtle graphics string `s` representing the `n`-th Hilbert curve iteration. The `a` is just scaling (line length) so the entire curve fit into unit square `<0,1>`.

For more info see related:

- [How can i produce multi point linear interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438865/2521214)