# Stippling stiches graphics pattern generation inside polygon

Tags: algorithm, graphics, drawing, shapes, stipple

I am working on a problem in which i have to generate a pattern similar to the one shown in this screenshot:

[image: polygon with sipple pattern inside it]

[image]

I have tried many different ways, but none are working.

I have seen some embroidery software which can generate this type of pattern, but I don't know the algorithm used to generate this patter.

Please help me, if someone knows anything about the algorithm.

Thank you!

Comment: no brother that was not helping.

Comment: It looks very similar to [2D Hilbert curve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50464341/2521214) just slightly distorted (maybe by some superponated random distrotion) ...

Comment: No  @Spektre there should be no end points in the curve, it should be closed.

Comment: hmm then I would start with inscribed circle and expand it as close to polygon as you can (by force field simulation) and then add random inward waves distortion not crossing itself until no space left ... interesting problems maybe I would try to code it ...